# how to update same column using update query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[image]

I am trying to update flag column based on cif. I cant figure it out. Kindly help to make update/merge query

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated `UPDATE`:

```sql
UPDATE table_name t
SET   flag = (SELECT x.flag
              FROM   table_name x
              WHERE  t.cif = x.cif
              AND    x.flag IS NOT NULL
              AND    ROWNUM = 1)
WHERE flag IS NULL;
```

Slightly more complicated but (probably) more efficient would be to use `MERGE` and correlate on the `ROWID` pseudo-column (which is a pointer to the row):

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT max_flag
  FROM   (
    SELECT flag,
           MAX(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY cif) AS max_flag
    FROM   table_name
  )
  WHERE  flag IS NULL
  AND    max_flag IS NOT NULL
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET   flag = src.max_flag;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (cif, flag) AS
SELECT 120, 'SF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 120, 'NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 151, 'NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 156, 'MF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 156, 'MF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 165, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 165, 'SF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 165, 'SF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 158, 'MF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 158, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `UPDATE` or `MERGE`, the table contains:

| CIF | FLAG |
| --- | --- |
| 120 | SF |
| 120 | NA |
| 151 | NA |
| 156 | MF |
| 156 | MF |
| 165 | SF |
| 165 | SF |
| 165 | SF |
| 158 | MF |
| 158 | MF |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q-NWxzM5)

Answer (score 3):

`merge`, as you said, could be one option.

Before:

```
SQL> select * From test;

       CIF FLAG
---------- ----
       120 SF
       120 NA
       165 SF
       165
       158 MF
       158

6 rows selected.
```

Merge:

```
SQL> merge into test a
  2    using (select b.cif, max(b.flag) flag
  3           from test b
  4           group by b.cif
  5          ) x
  6    on (a.cif = x.cif)
  7    when matched then update set
  8      a.flag = x.flag
  9      where a.flag is null;

2 rows merged.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * From test;

       CIF FLAG
---------- ----
       120 SF
       120 NA
       165 SF
       165 SF
       158 MF
       158 MF

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```